# Why do I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when trying to implement multithreading in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I have a main file where I plan to initiate the threads for my c++ program, for now, I only want to get one of the threads up and running before moving on to the others, but that is proving to be difficult. The purpose of the threads is for a TCP Server and Client to run at the same time, I have already tested my TCP code and it works, the issue now is running each one in its own thread. The following shows my main.cpp code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#include "./hdr/tcpip_server.hpp"
#include "./hdr/tcpip_client.hpp"

using namespace std;

tcpServer *backendServer;

//This is done because the callback function of std::thread tcpip_server_thread complains when I only use 'backendServer->Monitor' as my callback function
void StartThread (void) {backendServer->Monitor();}

int main (void) 
{
    /*Initiate and start TCP server thread*/

    std::thread tcpip_server_thread; // done to define object to be used outside the scope of the if statement below

    if (backendServer->Init())
    {
        std::thread tcpip_server_thread (StartThread);
    }

    /*Initiate and start data reader thread*/

    //std::thread tcpip_client_thread (tcpip_client);

    tcpip_server_thread.join();
    //tcpip_client_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The backendServer class is as follows:

```
class tcpServer
{
    private:

        int listening;
        sockaddr_in hint;
        sockaddr_in client;
        socklen_t clientSize;
        int clientSocket;
        char host[NI_MAXHOST];      
        char service[NI_MAXSERV];
        char buf[4096];

    public:

           bool Init ();
           void Monitor ();
};
```

The only error I am getting with this code is the one in the title, and I only get it when the code is executing, no errors are received while compiling the code.

When trying the following:

```
std::thread tcpip_server_thread (backendServer->Monitor);
```

I get the following warning:

> a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

and

> no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

Any help would be appreciated as this is my first project implementing threads.

Comment: It's a matter of *scope*, *life-time* and variable *shadowing*. In short: You have two very different and independent variables in different scope, both named `tcpip_server_thread`. One of these object can't be joined.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. `tcpServer *backendServer;` does not point anywhere and nothing in the code you posted changes that. THen this `backendServer->Monitor();` or this `backendServer->Monitor` goes boooooom

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think the code gets far enough for that to matter.  `backendServer` is never set to point to anything so the code fails when `StartThread()` dereferences the `NULL` pointer.

Comment: when you want an object you should use an object. Pointers only point, they do not much more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Some programmer dude I just want to make sure I understand what you are saying is to delete the line of code that only has ```std::thread tcpip_server_thread;``` in it? and then move the ,join into the scope of the code inside of the if-statement?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.  Rename the second `tcpip_server_thread` to `other_tcpip_server_thread` so you don't confuse the two.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So should I rather just define it as : ```tcpServer backendServer``` ?

Comment: I cannot tell. I don't understand the code. Do you want a pointer or an object? If it is the latter then you do not need a pointer

Comment: Just a side note: `std::thread` *can* handle member functions, but *if* using one you need to pass the instance on which to call the MF, too; this can occur both as reference or as pointer: `std::thread t(&tcpServer::Monitor, backendServer);` – you can even use function arguments – if so, the number of those the function expects and the one you pass to must match and the types at least be convertible.

Comment: pointers bring no inherent advantage. If you do not know why you used a poitner then nobody can.

Comment: `std::thread tcpip_server_thread(StartThread);` – this produces a *second* `std::thread` instance which runs out of scope immediately on closing the if-body (@Eljay hinted to already), instead you want: `tcpip_server_thread = std::thread(StartThread);`

Comment: Shortening all this discussion around pointer or object: Most likely you actually want `tcpServer backendServer;` (note the dropped astrisk!) – to make this work you need to change `tcpServer->` to `tcpServer.` as well on all occurrences.

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: Amending to @AndrewHenle: Actually that likely won't ever occur, more likely the code already fails at `if (backendServer->Init())`...

Comment: And yet a side note: You have a pretty strange naming convention, usually function names are in camel case (initial small letter – unless in Microsoft dominated environments, they're doing their own thing in this respect...) and class names in pascal case (initial capital letter – apart from standard library containers).

Answer (score 1):

The main issue of your code is an uninitialised (actually: zero-initialised) pointer:

```
tcpServer *backendServer;
```

Note that you never assign a value to! This results in (as a global variable) the pointer being initialised to `nullptr`, which you dereference illegally later on, e.g. at (the first time during the programme run)

```
 if (backendServer->Init())
```

which most likely caused the crash. A quick and dirty fix might look as:

```
int main()
{
    backendServer = new tcpServer(); // possibly with arguments, depending
                                     // on how your constructor looks like

    // the code you have so far

    delete backendServer; // avoid memory leak!!!
    return 0;
}
```

You spare all this hassle around manual memory management (-> explicit `delete`) if you use smart pointers instead, e.g. `std::unique_ptr`. However unless you possibly want to dynamically exchange the backend server, limit its life-time to anything else than the entire programme run or construct it with arguments that need to be retrieved/calculated within `main` before (none of appears pretty likely to me in given case) then you most likely are better off with a global *object*:

```
tcpServer backendServer; // note the dropped asterisk!
```

This way the object is created before entering `main` and correctly destructed after leaving.

As now no pointer any more you now refer to members via `.` instead of `->`, i.e. `backendServer.Monitor()` for instance.

You actually *can* construct a `std::thread` with member function pointers, too. You need, though, to pass the object on which this member function should get called to the thread as well:

```
std::thread(&tcpServer::Monitor, backendServer);
```

This works with both functions *and* objects, the latter are accepted by value, though, thus if you use a global *object* as recommended above you might rather want to create a pointer:

```
std::thread(&tcpServer::Monitor, &backendServer);
//                               ^ (!)
// note: NOT if your variable remains a pointer!!!
```

This way you can actually spare the global variable entirely and create the object within `main` and the `StartThread` (actually you should better have named it `RunThread`) gets entirely obsolete as well.

Alternatives to are converting `Monitor` function into an `operator()` or adding such one as

```
void tcpServer::operator()()
{
    this->Monitor();
}
```

which makes the object itself callable, thus you could pass it directly to the thread's constructor (`std::thread(std::ref(backendServer));` with `std::ref` preventing the object getting copied) or using a lambda:

```
std::thread([&]() { backendServer.Monitor(); });
```

both with the same advantage as providing the member function that you can spare global variable and `StartThread` function.

Still your code reveals *another* problem:

```
if (backendServer->Init())
{
    std::thread tcpip_server_thread(StartThread);
}
```

You create here a *second* local variable `tcpip_server_thread` which, as long as it exists, *hides* the previous one, but which runs out of scope and thus gets destructed again right after the end of the if-body!

Instead you want to assign the newly created thread to the already existing variable, which would look like:

```
tcpip_server_thread = std::thread(StartThread);
```

Actually you get nicer code if you move the entire thread-code *into* the if block:

```
// no thread code left here any more

if(backendServer->Init())
{
    std::thread tcpip_server_thread(StartThread);

    // start second thread here, too!

    tcpip_server_thread.join();
}

// no thread code left here any more
```

Finally you should not `join` a thread that actually has failed to start. You spot this by checking if the thread is `joinable`

```
std::thread tcpip_server_thread (StartThread);
if(tcpip_server_thread.joinable())
{
    // see above for correct construction!
    std::thread tcpip_client_thread(tcpip_client);

    if(tcpip_client_thread.joinable())
    {
        tcpip_server_thread.join();
    }
    else
    {
        // you might need some appropriate error handling like
        // printing/logging a warning message
        // and possibly stop the server thread
    }
}
else
{
    error handling, see above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Initializing `backendServer`:**

`backendServer` is a pointer to `tcpServer`, but it is uninitialized (and does not point to any valid object).
Therefore  `backendServer->Init();` invokes **UB** [`Undefined Behavior`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and likely to crash.
If you must use a pointer you must allocate it. Better still use a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.
But in your case I believe the best solution is not to use a pointer at all, and define `backendServer` as a local variable in `main`:

```
int main(void) 
{
    tcpServer backendServer;
    // ...
}
```

This will require accessing it with `backendServer.` instead of `backendServer->`.

**2. The thread issue:**

At the moment, you have 2 `tcpip_server_thread` variables.
The 2nd one inside the `if` is shadowing the 1st one you have before.
When you get out of the `if`'s scope, the 2nd `tcpip_server_thread` will be destroyed, and a `std::thread` must be joined before destruction.
Later on you attempt to `join` the 1st one which has not even started, causing a 2nd problem.

In order to fix it:

1. Inside the if, do not declare a new variable. Instead use the one you already have:

   ```
   tcpip_server_thread = std::thread(StartThread);
   ```

   If you made `backendServer` a local in `main` as suggested above, you can use a lambda that captures it by reference:

   ```
   tcpip_server_thread = std::thread(
                  [&backendServer]() { backendServer.Monitor();});
   //--------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------------
   ```
2. Before you [`join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the thread check that it is [`joinable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable). In the current code this will not be the case if you didn't enter the `if` that started the thread:

   ```
   if (tcpip_server_thread.joinable())
   {
       tcpip_server_thread.join();
   }
   ```

**A side note:** [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I will try this and let you know, thanks @wohlstad